# Read time stamp from notepad using batch script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm looking solution for below issue :

We reload our application everyday and it will create the log file on daily.
sometimes the log stop writing because of some issues related to CPU usage and other strange stuff.
Now we want to monitor the log file on every 5 mins, if anything doesn't get updated in the log file then it should trigger an email.
The log file keep updating every 1 min, when the reload of file goes smooth.

I need read time stamp in the log file.The log file has time stamp column , it will write content in the log file in every 5 mins. so i need to read the time stamp inside the file for every 5 mins , if anything doesn't return more then 5 mins then i should trigger alert.

Is there any way to implement the above scenario using batch script or power shell or any other idea's to monitor log file is welcome.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: haven't tried anything David, looking for best solution ! Please suggest me how we can do ?

Comment: `(Get-Item log.file).LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Not better ` If ((Get-Item log.file).LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)) {send-mail ...}`

Answer (score 1):

You definately can use Powershell for this purpose!

Make sure you have changed **Powershell Execution Policy** for scripts. You can change it like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Here's the simple script that would handle it. It could be made as one/two liners of course, but i tried to make it to be more readable/understandable, there:

```
$FilePath = 'C:\log.txt' #Log file location
$Minutes = 5 #LastWriteTime older than 5 minutes from current time.

#General email parameters
$SMTP = 'your.smtp.server.local'
$From = 'yourserviceaccount@contoso.com'
$To = 'someperson@contoso.com'
$Subject = 'Action Required'
$Body = 'Log file havent been written from more than {0} minutes!' -f $Minutes

$LastWriteTime = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $FilePath).LastWriteTime
if ($LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$Minutes))
{
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTP -Port 25 -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Priority High
}
```

You could then make a Scheduled Task that will trigger the script file every N-minutes.

Comment: Kirill, I need read time stamp in the log file.The log file has time stamp column , it will write content in the log file in every 5 mins. so i need to read the time stamp inside the file for every 5 mins , if anything doesn't return more then 5 mins then i should trigger alert.

Comment: @AnilKumar, how's timestamp format look like in your log file?

Comment: here it is : 
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      CPU Target                    x64
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      Operating System              Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1 (64 bit edition)
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      Wow64 mode                    Not using 
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      PreferredCompression          2
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      EnableParallelReload          1
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      ParallelizeQvdLoads           1
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      AutoSaveAfterReload           0
11/28/2016 11:50:46 AM:      BackupBeforeReload            0

Comment: Why would you need to look inside the log file? If it has been changed by any means it would change its last time write value anyway.